Почему возникает IllegalStateException при удалении элементов из листа?
Как избавиться от IllegalStateException в коде:
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Iterator1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<>();
        al1.add("Sasha");
        al1.add("Raul");
        al1.add("Mary");
        al1.add("Sasha");
        al1.add("Elena");

        Iterator<String> iterator1 = al1.iterator();
        while(iterator1.hasNext()) {
//            System.out.println(iterator1.next());//выовд с помощю iterator'а
            iterator1.remove();
            iterator1.next();
        }
        System.out.println(al1.toString());
    }
}


Читать документацию для метода Iterator::remove: throws ... IllegalStateException - if the next method has not yet been called, or the remove method has already been called after the last call to the next method, т.е. перед вызовом remove всегда нужно вызвать метод next соответствующего итератора.

Поменяйте местами remove() и next(). next() возвращает элемент, который потом удаляется remove(), а у вас наоборот, поэтому и ошибка.
Iterator<String> iterator1 = al1.iterator();
while(iterator1.hasNext()) {
    iterator1.next();
    iterator1.remove();
}


IllegalStateException возникает по причине неправильного удаления элемента листа. Чтобы избавиться от этой ошибки следует избавиться от итератора и воспользоваться уже готовым методом removeAll.
public class RemoveAllExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try { 
        ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<>();
        al1.add("Sasha");
        al1.add("Raul");
        al1.add("Mary");
        al1.add("Sasha");
        al1.add("Elena");

            // печать al1 
            System.out.println("ArrayList перед "
                               + "removeAll() операцией : "                               + al1); 

            // Создадим другой лист  ArrayList<String> 
            ArrayList<String> al2 = new ArrayList<>(al1);   

            // печать al2 
            System.out.println("Элементы коллекции"                               + " которые будут удалены : "                               + al2); 

            // Удалить элементы из al1 
            // находящиеся в al2 
            // используя метод removeAll()  
            al1.removeAll(al2); 

            // печать al1 
            System.out.println("ArrayList после "
                               + "removeAll() операции : "                               + al1);              
      } catch (NullPointerException e) {  
        System.out.println("Ошибка : " + e); 
      } 
   }
}

Заметим, что в коде используется try-catch блок, потому, что может возникнуть NullPointerException если этот список содержит нулевой элемент, а указанная коллекция не допускает нулевых элементов (необязательно) или если указанная коллекция имеет значение null.
